# Use different paths for public and private resources Jersey + Spring boot

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot, jersey

I'm using Spring boot + Jersey + Spring security, I want to have public and private endpoints, I want an schema as follow:

- **/rest** -- My root context
- **/public** -- I want to place my public endpoints in this context, It must be inside of the root context like `/rest/public/pings`
- **/private** -- I want to place my private endpoints in this context, It must be inside of the root context like `/rest/private/accounts`

I have my configuration as follow:

**Jersey** configuration:

```
@Configuration
@ApplicationPath("/rest")
public class RestConfig extends ResourceConfig {
    public RestConfig() {
        register(SampleResource.class);
    }
}
```

**Spring security** configuration:

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

........

    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/rest/public/**").permitAll();
        http.antMatcher("/rest/**").authorizeRequests().anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated().and().httpBasic();
        http.csrf().disable();
    }

}
```

The question is how can I register two application paths inside of my /rest context, one for /public and the other one for /private ?

NOTE: I tried to create another ResourceConfig as follow:

```
@Configuration
@ApplicationPath("/rest/public")
public class RestPublicConfig extends ResourceConfig{
    public RestPublicConfig() {
        register(PingResource.class);
    }
}
```

But I'm getting the next error:

```
 No qualifying bean of type [org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: restConfig,restPublicConfig
```

Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 23):

In a servlet container, the Jersey runtime, runs as either a servlet or as a servlet filter. How spring boot configures servlets and filters is through `ServletRegistrationBean`s and `FilterRegistrationBeans`, respectively. To get an idea of how that configuration works behind scenes, you can look at the source code for the [`JerseyAutoConfiguration`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/7ed64f0677709e460fbcbc19539487d8f7e59965/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jersey/JerseyAutoConfiguration.java#L145)

In the `JerseyAutoConfiguration`, you can see that a `ResourceConfig` is injected, and that is the `ResourceConfig` used to create the Jersey servlet or Jersey filter (depending on your choice of configuration). So the reason for the error is that you can't have ambiguous beans, which you have two `ResourceConfig` beans. So Spring doesn't know which one to inject.

What you *can* do though, is use two different servlets for each `ResourceConfig`. The problem is that Spring Boot only hooks you up with one servlet for Jersey, so you need to configure the other one yourself. There are two options:

1. Use the Spring Boot auto-configuration for one of the Jersey applications, and add another `ServletRegistrationBean` for your other one. The one thing to note is that the `ResourceConfig` for your created `ServletRegistrationBean` should not be a Spring component (i.e. no `@Component` or `@Configuration`), or else you will still face the same error.

   ```
    public class PublicConfig extends ResourceConfig {
        public PublicConfig() {
            register(PingResource.class);
        }
    }
    ...
    // in your Spring Boot configuration class
    @Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean publicJersey() {
        ServletRegistrationBean publicJersey 
                = new ServletRegistrationBean(new ServletContainer(new PublicConfig()));
        publicJersey.addUrlMappings("/rest/public/*");
        publicJersey.setName("PublicJersey");
        publicJersey.setLoadOnStartup(0);
        return publicJersey;
    }
   ```
2. Don't use the Spring Boot configuration at all. Just create two `ServletRegistrationBean`s. In this case, none of your `ResourceConfig` classes should be Spring beans.

   ```
    @Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean publicJersey() {
        ServletRegistrationBean publicJersey 
                = new ServletRegistrationBean(new ServletContainer(new PublicConfig()));
        publicJersey.addUrlMappings("/rest/public/*");
        publicJersey.setName("PublicJersey");
        publicJersey.setLoadOnStartup(0);
        return publicJersey;
    }

    @Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean privateJersey() {
        ServletRegistrationBean privateJersey 
               = new ServletRegistrationBean(new ServletContainer(new PrivateConfig()));
        privateJersey.addUrlMappings("/rest/private/*");
        privateJersey.setName("PrivateJersey");
        privateJersey.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        return privateJersey;
    }
   ```

Personally, I prefer the second option, as it is easier to reason about the configurations when they are all in one place.

Another thing to note is that the two Jersey applications will be completely independent, meaning you will need to register providers (like filters) for both applications

Comment: I used the second option, Thank you so much, It was really helpful :)

Comment: Thank you! Was struggling with this.

Comment: I've seen other examples of this where instead of passing the ResourceConfig into the ServletContainer constructor, it is registered on an ApplicationContext (one per servlet) `AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext applicationContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext() applicationContext.register(PrivateConfig.class)`  How does that relate to this?

Comment: @Rhubarb The requirement is that the ResourceConfig be a Spring bean. It's the same as annotating the ResourceConfig with `@Component/@Configuration`. This is how Spring boot knows to to autoconfiguration for Jersey. Under the hood, Spring Boot will create the ServletContainer passing in the ResourceConfig. In the example above, we are not using the Spring Boot auto configuration and instead doing all the configuration ourselves.

Answer (score 0):

You won't be allowed to create two beans for your Resource Class. You can achieve what you are trying to achieve using a single Resource Class as well.

Here is an example:

```
@Path("rest")
public class SampleResourceClass {

  @Path("/public/pings")
  @GET
  public Responce getPings(){
    /* Code Here */
  }

  @Path("/private/accounts")
  @GET
  public Response getAccounts(){
    /* Code Here */
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I understand this, but I want to create many public endpoints, and in this way I only can use this classs.

Answer (score 0):

The error you are seeing is not related to your security config, you may want to take a look at this ticket, https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/3260

If you want to permit all traffic to endpoints past `/public` you can add the `RequestMatcher` to the Spring Security ignore list.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {

        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/rest/public/**");
     }

     protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

          http.authorizeRequests().antMatcher("/rest/private/**")
          .anyRequest().authenticated().and()
          .httpBasic().and()
          .csrf().disable()
     }

}
```

http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#jc