# Spring Boot: Determining what autoconfiguration are applied to jersey?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jersey, jersey-2.0

Following the online docs for adding jersey to Sring boot, it appears I just need to include the following package

```
spring-boot-starter-jersey
```

Actually, it states that Spring Boot provides automatic configuration by including this package.

Where can I find out what exactly is happening?

If I don't add this package then what is NOT configured?

I tried searching for the package in google but got no specific explanation only saying that it automatically configures, but configures what?

I would like to know a little more of what is happening behind the scenes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend learning a little more about how Spring Boot works to provide the automatic configuration in general.

A good reference is the spring boot reference guide. http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.3.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#common-application-properties

You can look at the common application properties in appendix A to see what all spring allows you to configure out of the box.

The Reference guide also gives a high level of what "spring-boot-starter-jersey" if you search for it on the page.

They also have a few samples that you can go through and debug to follow along if that is a way for you to learn.

Hope that gives you a starting point for learning!

Answer (score 2):

All of the auto-configuration code for *all* that Spring Boot supports is in the [spring-boot-autoconfigure](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-autoconfigure) module. If you look through the packages, you will see a jersey package.

The "starter" modules generally do not have any code (of course unless it is a third-party module). How it works is that the code in the auto-configuration has some annotations that are `@ConditionalOnXxx`, where the condition be anything from a class being on the classpath. If this class is not available, then the auto-configuration will not take place. That's pretty much all adding the jersey starter module does: it [adds the jersey dependencies](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-starters/spring-boot-starter-jersey) so that the auto-configurer will applied.

Now what exactly is being auto-configured specifically for Jersey? Check out the source for the [`JerseyAutoConfiguration`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jersey/JerseyAutoConfiguration.java). Basically what you are going to see is your `ResourceConfig` being injected into the configurer. From that `ResourceConfig`, it creates Jersey's `ServletContainer` (which is the main entry point for Jersey.

Then, depending on our properties configuration, either a `FilterRegistrationBean` or a `ServletRegistrationBean` is created as a Spring bean, wrapping Jersey's `ServletContainer`. Jersey can be created as a Servlet or a Servlet Filter. Whichever one we configure we be used.

And that's it for the Jersey configuration. Spring Boot will get a servlet container (e.g. Tomcat, Jetty) from some other auto-configuration, and take the `Filter/ServletRegistrationBean` and add the `Servlet/Filter` to that servlet container.

Also, not really that important, but the auto-configuration also give us some Jackson configuration helpers. For example, instead of [configuring our own ContextResolver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31703546/2587435), we can just configure an `ObjectMapper` Spring bean.

That's really all you get. It's nothing so spectacular that you couldn't just [do it yourself](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35496771/2587435) without depending on the auto-configuration.