# How to make a spring-boot Jersey application have an alias for the @ApplicationPath value?

Tags: java, spring-boot, servlets, jax-rs

We have a bunch of SpringBoot applications, all presently using Jersey (JAX-RS) to provide REST services.

All of them have an "Application" class that extends `SpringBootServletInitializer` and with a `@SpringBootApplication` annotation.

They all have a class that extends `org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig` where the constructor has some "`register()`" calls to register jax-rs controllers.  This class also has an `@ApplicationPath` annotation that specifies the url path added to the context-path that all of its controllers listen on.

We have a situation where we would like to define "aliases" for the value provided to "`@ApplicationPath`".  I'm looking for ways to implement this.  I note that the javadoc for `ApplicationPath` says this:

> When published in a Servlet container, the value of the application
> path may be overridden using a servlet-mapping element in the web.xml.

Now that says "overridden", which may or may not be what I want.  I also note that if I had a plain web.xml, I believe I can have multiple servlet-mapping elements pointing to the same servlet.  Does that map both paths?  With a conventional SpringBoot app, I don't have a web.xml, so I'm not sure if that helps me.

I note that when I inspect `org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer`, I see there is code that appear to be manipulating objects that seem like they are analogs of what is defined in the web.xml, so perhaps there's something I can do with that api to add an additional servlet mapping?

Comment: The application path can be configured in your application.properties using spring.jersey.application-path. Is that what you were looking for?

Comment: No. the @ApplicationPath annotation already does that. What we need is the ability to define aliases of that. I need to do something like what JerseyServletContainerInitializer does, but augmenting the servlet, not creating it, and of course I have to ensure that my initializer runs after the other one.

Comment: Can you [use a ServletContainerProvider](https://github.com/psamsotha/jersey-web-initializer)?

Comment: I have no idea. Can you give me a little more than just a link to a class?

Comment: It's more than just a link to a class. It's a whole poc repo on how to use it.

Comment: So to be clear, you are suggesting that I can use this IN ADDITION to the existing SpringBoot and Jersey ContainerInitializer class, and the execution order of these won't matter, and it will just work?

Comment: Curiously, I tried running my service in the debugger, setting breakpoints in the various classes implementing ServletContainerInitializer, and it only stopped in TomcatStarter.  It didn't stop in SpringBootServletInitializer or JerseyServletContainerInitializer. That is perplexing.

Comment: Oh wait nevermind. There JerseyServletContainerInitializaer is not used with an embedded server. I totally forgot. Everything is set up in the Spring Boot JerseyAutoConfiguration. Really, you could just override the the behavior of the JerseyAutoConfiguration and just create your own Jersey servlet. Just look at the source code of the JerseyAutoConfiguration. To disable it, you could simply just not annotate the ResourceConfig with `@Component` or `@Configuration`.

Comment: Here's an example https://stackoverflow.com/a/35496771/2587435